# Calling Get method dynamically based on name of property

Tags: java, lombok

I have a Lombok class

```
@Data
public class A {
  private long exp;
  private String id;
  private String code;

  ...about 50 more properties

}
```

And created an instance from class A, named `a`, and initialize it with some values. How would I do the for loop over the properties and call the method `a.get(PropertyName)` (based on the Property Name) to extract the values?

Answer (score 3):

Reflection API is your friend. Assuming the following class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class MyObject {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean active;
}
```

### Declared field access

The easiest would be reading the declared field directly as you can use the name field.

```
@SneakyThrows
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public static <T> T get(String fieldName, Object instance, Class<?> instanceClass) {
    return (T) instanceClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName).get(instance);
}
```

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(1L, "John", true);
String name = get("name", myObject, MyObject.class);
System.out.println(name); // John
```

- **Pros:** You can use the field name directly
- **Cons:** You need to cast to the field type. You need to handle `NoSuchFieldException` and `IllegalAccessException` and you should not rely on the reflection if not needed. Also as you access the field directly, the getter method is ignored.

### Getter access

The things come a bit complicated as `boolean` can appear among the declared fields, because the getter is called `isActive` instead of `getActive`, so you need to handle this case:

```
@SneakyThrows
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public static <T> T get(String fieldName, Object instance, Class<?> instanceClass) {
    String fieldNameBase = fieldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + fieldName.substring(1);
    try {
        return (T) instanceClass.getDeclaredMethod("get" + fieldNameBase).invoke(instance);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        return  (T) instanceClass.getDeclaredMethod("is" + fieldNameBase).invoke(instance);
    }
}
```

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(1L, "John", true);
boolean active = get("active", myObject, MyObject.class);
System.out.println(active); // true
```

- **Pros:** The getter is guaranteed to be invoked
- **Cons:** The same as the previous way **and** the implementation is a bit more complicated

---

**Disclaimer:** This is not a production-ready code and you might want to perform some exception handling. However, I hope my answer gets you an idea of how to approach it.

---

**Edit:** If you don't like the `is` prefix that Lombok adds to the `boolean` you can disable it using the `lombok.getter.noIsPrefix` property. Read more at [Lombok: Configuration system](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration).

Comment: Thank you, I don't think any field will be a boolean in my case.

Comment: ... but you should be ready to handle it once it comes. I doubt the one who adds a boolean field would also mind this implementation. So I suggest either handle it the way I proposed or configure Lombok to generate only `getXXX` methods even for `boolean` fields. :) Do you have any more edits/questions?